# Can't switch from Local Windows Debugger to Local Machine (VS 2019)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, xaml, debugging

i'm creating a C++/XAML (UWP) app. Initially, i saw as debug default "Local Machine", but now i see "Local Windows Debugger" and when i debug my application the compiler find many exceptions in the file called "base.h". So i tried to reswitch to "Local Machine", but i never saw the element in "Configuration Property" menu. What can i do? I Link you an image (italian)   [My situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sxU2O.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have to do is just open your `.vcxproj.user` file for edit and change "*WindowsLocalDebugger*" value to "*GamingDesktopDebugger*" (it is located in the `DebuggerFlavor` field).